# Why my Pycharm IDE is not listening my voice

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a voice assistant. But I have a problem. The problem is that pycharm is not listening my voice. it stills running. But did not giving my result.

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with Pycharm, and not your code? Have you tried to run your code somewhere else?

Comment: yes. it could be a problem in my laptop. But how can i fix it???

Comment: First, try to run the code via the command line. If that doesn't work, try on a different computer. If that works, try to find the problem with your laptop, maybe your mic isn't working? If that doesn't work, the problem is most probably with your code.